# How to make a question about which job will allow our son to advocate for his calling and life mission on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I asked the question [What full-time, well-paying job fits my son who wants to advocate physician-assisted suicide?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/37567/30519) on Parenting.SE and it was closed and then deleted. It received an [answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/37568/30519) I found helpful. We hadn't thought of geriatrics before.

In short, my son has to choose which university subject to apply for. His calling and life mission is to fight for physician-assisted suicide and he wants to aim for a job that allows him this. The job must be full-time and pay well over minimum wage.

**How can I make this question on topic on Parenting.SE?**

Comment: I edited your question a bit, making the title more descriptive so people know what this very question is about. I also updated its body so people who can't see deleted questions know what it's about.

Comment: The most famous case in the US re: death with dignity is about [Brittany Maynard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittany_Maynard). A Geriatrician had nothing to do with her ability to choose death. Her doctor was a family physician (who now runs a hospice.) So... Primarily Opinion Based. Maynard herself was a significant moving force in Death with Dignity laws in the US, not her doctor. Her advocacy helped four more states to adopt assisted suicide laws. For a physician's role, see [Dr. Jack Kevorkian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kevorkian), a Pathologist.

Comment: On SE, we try to provide the proper context to the quotes.  In the A in the deleted thread, only item #1 is about _"geriatrics"_. Item #3 is: _"Health care in general: Examples: physician, nurse."_ This category covers examples you provide in your comment (family physician, pathologist). Seems like you are saying that this thread is primarily opinion-based, and providing the (fact-based?) A for the original deleted Q on meta and in a comment, which is not the right place for it. Would you care to provide your helpful info as an A the original OP's Q? Feel free to undelete the thread if needed.

Comment: @TimurShtatland - The point is actually that a doctor of any kind is not likely to be useful towards getting Death with Dignity laws on the books. One has a **much** better chance to do that if one is an effective, sympathetic spokesperson in need of such a law, e.g. Maynard.

Comment: @timur - the question is off topic, so it will not be undeleted. We do not want to answer off topic questions as that only encourages them.

Comment: Related questions and discussion on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/134238) and [Academia Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4513).

Answer (score 2):

The question is *off topic* on Parenting.SE and I do not see how it can be made *on topic*. The reasons are two fundamental problems:

1. It's **not** about parenting. What career for a child to choose, for whatever reasons, is out of scope of this site. There is no parenting problem to be solved here.
2. It's **primarily opinion-based**. There's no clear correct answer to what career is best for your son. You are asking *What do you think? Any other suggestions?* Idea generation questions are not a good fit.

That it's not *on topic* here does not necessarily mean it's a bad question (or that someone felt offended). It's just that Stack Exchange is optimised for a special type of questions - those with one correct answer in principle. The question then (hopefully) receives several answers trying to solve the problem and one does it best and gets accepted. This means for a stack like Parenting.SE that we have to restrict ourselves to these types of questions, too.

Stack Exchange furthermore strives to become a knowledge repository, which further shapes the types of questions allowed on specific stacks. This one is dedicated to parenting, so we only want parenting questions. This way, visitors can most effectively use this resource. And experts on parenting (e. g. parents) can find questions for them to answer.

If you want to know which career is best for your son, it will not be *on topic* here. Editing won't help.

Here are links to relevant help center articles

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

As @Anne Daunted stated, this can't be made *on topic*. It's a question about career choices that happens to be about your child. That's not parenting; that's career advice.

I can't think of a stack site that would regard your question as on topic.

I'm glad you found a helpful answer. It was helpful *to you*. It is not likely to be helpful to a large number of other parents, or even of interest to them, nor it it likely that a large number of parents are likely to try to sway their child to go into Geriatrics so that they can help elderly people to die with dignity.

FWIW, I happen to be a physician who believes in death with dignity. But it has nothing whatsoever to do with parenting.